durable function working on local but not on the cloud
I am currently facing a very strange issue with the code I wrote for an Azure Function. It works fine in the UAT environment and also works locally when using local.settings.json to connect to the production environment. However, when deployed to the actual production environment, the orchestrator fails to run. There are no error or warning messages, even though I’ve added extra logging and try-catch blocks however nothing appears in the logs.
What’s even more unusual is that not all orchestrators fail; some work while others don’t, and I haven’t found any discernible pattern when comparing them. For instance, one of the failing orchestrators uses the following code:

var instanceId = await starter.StartNewAsync(nameof(Orchestrator1), $"{name}-{Guid.NewGuid()}.{fileExt}",
                new {
                    FileName = $"{name}.{fileExt}",
                    QuoteNumber = quoteNumber
                });

The Orchestrator1 does not get triggered at all. I have verified that all the variables involved are valid and retrievable. I’ve also confirmed that the local.settings.json file matches the production environment’s configuration exactly. The run time currently is .net6 and the package installed is "Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.DurableTask" version 2.11.1
Could anyone help me understand why this might be happening? What could cause it to work locally (with the production environment settings) and in UAT, but fail in the actual production deployment?

Can you provide full code?

It worked for me using below code:
[Function("Function1_HttpStart")]
public static async Task<HttpResponseData> HttpStart(
    [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post")] HttpRequestData req,
    [DurableClient] DurableTaskClient ricl,
    FunctionContext executionContext)
{
    ILogger ri_lg = executionContext.GetLogger("Function1_HttpStart");

    string rith_bd = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
    var rith_val = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<JsonElement>(rith_bd);
    string peru = rith_val.GetProperty("name").GetString() ?? "default";
    string extu = rith_val.GetProperty("fileExt").GetString() ?? "txt";
    string ri_qn = rith_val.GetProperty("quoteNumber").GetString() ?? "000";

    var ri_in = new
    {
        FileName = $"{peru}.{extu}",
        QuoteNumber = ri_qn
    };

    ri_lg.LogInformation("Hello Rithwik Bojja, Starting orchestration with FileName: {FileName}, QuoteNumber: {QuoteNumber}", ri_in.FileName, ri_qn);
    string rid = await ricl.ScheduleNewOrchestrationInstanceAsync(
        nameof(Function1),
        ri_in);

    ri_lg.LogInformation("Hello Rithwik Bojja, Started orchestration with ID = '{instanceId}'.", rid);
    return await ricl.CreateCheckStatusResponseAsync(req, rid);
}

Here i have used Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.DurableTask" Version="1.1.1"  for .net 6 to make it compatible.
csproj:
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v4</AzureFunctionsVersion>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker" Version="1.23.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.DurableTask" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Http" Version="3.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Http.AspNetCore" Version="1.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk" Version="1.17.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WorkerService" Version="2.22.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.ApplicationInsights" Version="1.2.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="host.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="local.settings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Using Include="System.Threading.ExecutionContext" Alias="ExecutionContext" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>

Output:
Local:

then:

After Deploying to Azure:


